# How can I Display Code and Pseudo-Code Side-By-Side in a Document?

Tags: documentation

I want to display code on a page with some psuedo-code in another column beside it -- so it appears like two separate documents side-by-side. As you scroll down, both columns/documents should stay in lock-step.  How can I do this?

Background:  If you're interested to know why, here it is:
We are doing code presentation for a client, because the code includes complex math that *must* be precise in its logic. The client is skilled in mathematics but less-skilled in programming. So I would like to show pseudo-code in an adjacent column to make it very easy to follow the overall direction of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well nobody ever suggested anything. I looked at generating a PDF, but I couldn't find an easy way to generate a document without word wrap interfering.

What I ended up using was GitHub. This is the process I used:

1. I created a file for the code to review.
2. I committed the file and pushed it to the repository.
3. I used Find and Replace with regular expressions in Visual Studio to delete all the comments in one step.
4. I committed the file and pushed it to the repository with all the comments now removed.
5. I used Undo on the file to add all the comments back in and pushed it one last time.

After that, I was able to go to GitHub.com and visit that file in the repository. By looking at the history of the file, GitHub automatically shows revision history changes of any commit side-by-side with the previous version.  It looks very nicely formatted. The result is that all of the code has a green highlighted block and the comments are separated.  Or it can be viewed opposite of that with the comments highlighted and the code normal.  There is no word-wrap which is desirable.  It keeps all the lines separated the way they were formatted in the source document.

This solution worked out because the client can be given access to the repository. Then I can send a direct link to a history snapshot of the file for the client to see the code and comment version side-by-side.  It's very easy.